# How to prove this $\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sqrt{b^2+(n^2-1)c^2}\le (a+b+c)^2+(n-3)(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, radicals, muirhead-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $n$ be postive integer,show that
$$a\sqrt{b^2+(n^2-1)c^2}+b\sqrt{c^2+(n^2-1)a^2}+c\sqrt{a^2+(n^2-1)b^2}\le (a+b+c)^2+(n-3)(ab+bc+ac)$$

For $n=1$ it suffices to show that
$$ab+bc+ac\le (a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ac)=a^2+b^2+c^2$$  this is equivalent to the obvious inequality
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0$$
But How to prove by $n\ge 2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq2$ we have $\sqrt{a^2+(n^2-1)b^2}\leq\frac{a^2+(n-1)ab+(n^2-n)b^2}{a+(n-1)b}\Leftrightarrow b^2(a-b)^2\geq0$.

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{c(a^2+(n-1)ab+(n^2-n)b^2)}{a+(n-1)b}\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+(n-1)ab)$$ or
$$n(n-2)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)+(n-1)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4b+(n-1)a^4c+(n-3)a^3b^2-(2n-3)a^3c^2)\geq0$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4b-a^4c-3a^3b^2+3a^3c^2)+n\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4c+a^3b^2-2a^3c^2)\geq0$$
and since $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4c+a^3b^2-2a^3c^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(b^4a-2b^3a^2+a^3b^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}ab^2(a-b)^2\geq0$,

it remains to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4b-a^4c-3a^3b^2+3a^3c^2)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4c+a^3b^2-2a^3c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2)\geq0$$
which is Muirhead.

Done!

Comment: the first inequality how to get it?

Comment: @communnites By squaring of the both sides.

Comment: Hello,I ask How to get this right hand?not ask How to prove

Comment: @communnites Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+n^2-1}-\frac{x^2+kx+l}{x+m}$. Hence, $f(1)=0$, $f'(1)=0$ and the inequality must be true.

Comment: Why are you bumping a lot of questions just to change \sum to \sum\limits or \int to \int\limits? It doesn't improve the question or answer in any way. It's purely a stylistic choice.

Comment: @user232456 I just edit it because after my editing it seems better.

Comment: I personally feel that \int\limits actually makes it look worse in some cases. And most people use simply \int or \sum. But in any case, when you edit an old question (or answer), it bumps the question to the front page. And bumping an old question just to make a minor change that doesn't really improve the question (or answer) is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: @user232456 I understood you. Thank you!